# PHP SSH2 echo to file for stop session

Tags: php, linux, screen, ssh2-exec

I want to create a stop.sh file for stopping screen session.

```
$test = "screen_name";
```

This is the command:

```
kill -15 $(screen -ls | grep '[0-9]*\.$test' | sed -E 's/\s+([0-9]+)\..*/\1/'`)
```

And I want to create this file with php ssh2_exec like this:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, "echo 'kill -15 $(screen -ls | grep '[0-9]*\.$test' | sed -E 's/\s+([0-9]+)\..*/\1/')' > /home/test/stop.sh");
```

But I get this:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I tried:

```
kill -15 $(screen -ls | grep \'[0-9]*\.$test\' | sed -E \'s/\s+([0-9]+)\..*/\1/\')
```

But this is not working.

Comment: You're missing `(`

Comment: Within double quotes PHP will try to parse code that begins with `$` so in that command where you have `$(screen -ls.....` my belief is that PHP baulks at that bracket because no variable would begin with a bracket. You should try escaping that `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment regarding parsing anything within double quotes that begins with a `$` you could try an alternative to construct the command string by using `sprintf` and wrapping the whole command in single quotes but with double quotes within.

```
$test='banana';

$cmd=sprintf('kill -15 $(screen -ls | grep "[0-9]*\.%s" | sed -E "s/\s+([0-9]+)\..*/\1/") > /home/test/stop.sh', $test );
echo $cmd;
```

Which yields a finalised command string:

```
kill -15 $(screen -ls | grep "[0-9]*\.banana" | sed -E "s/\s+([0-9]+)\..*/\1/") > /home/test/stop.sh
```

which looks OK, so you could then do:

```
ssh2_exec( $connection, $cmd );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this:

```
$text = 'echo \'kill -15 $(screen -ls | grep \'[0-9]*\.'$test.'\' | sed -E \'s/\s+([0-9]+)\..*/\1/\')\' > /home/test/stop.sh\' ;
ssh2_exec($connection, $text);
```